# Confusion between (arry+i) and *(arry+i) in 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion

I have small confusion about these two expressions: `(arry+i)` and `*(arry+i)` in a 2D array, both expression gives same output which is the address of i-th element of the array.

Why is it, shouldn't `*(arry+i)` point out value of i-th element instead of i-th address.

```
main() {
    int arry[3][4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4,
                       4, 3, 2, 8,
                       7, 8, 9, 0
                      };

    printf("%u\n", arry + 1);
    printf("%u\n", *(arry + 1));
};
```

Output comes out to be:

```
2346225936
2346225936
```

Where as I was expecting it to be:

```
2346225936
4
```

Comment: What is the value of the array in ith element?

Comment: We will need a sample code to understand it better.

Comment: `%u` it not the proper format specifier for pointers. Use `%p` and convert the parameter to `void*`.

Comment: Why do you expect `4`? `*(array+1)` is the same as `array[1]` which is of type `int[4]`, not `int`.

Comment: but if base type of *(array+1) is int[4] then  *(arry+1)+1 shouldn't give 2346225940 (which is output I see).

Comment: @Milan `*(array + 1)` do have type `int[4]` but when you use it in an expression it decays into `int*`. So `*(array + 1)` is equivalent to `int* tmp = *(array + 1); tmp = tmp + 1`. In other words - it will output 2346225940. Try `*(*(array + 1) + 1)` to access the integer value.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a two-dimensional array declared like

```
T a[M][N];
```

where `T` is some type when the expression `( a + i )` has the type `T( * )[N]` and points to the i-th "row" of the array.

The expression `*( a + i )` (that is dereferencing a pointer of the above shown type) yields the lvalue of the pointed "row" that is an array of the type `T[N]`. Used in expressions an array designator is converted to pointer to its first element. In this case the array is converted to the type `T *`.

So the both pointers of the types `T ( * )[N]` and `T *` point to the beginning of the same extent of memory where the i-th "row" is accommodated. That is the values of the pointers are equal each other but the pointers themselves have different types.

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed multiple causes for confusion:

- `arry` is defined as an array of 3 arrays of 4 `int`. The initializer would be more readable as:

  ```
    int arry[3][4] = {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 4, 3, 2, 8 },
        { 7, 8, 9, 0 }
    };
  ```

`arry` is the name of this 2D array, which is different from a pointer to an array. Its type is `int[3][4]`. What causes the confusion is the automatic conversion of arrays to pointers to their first element that occurs implicitly whenever they are used in expressions or when passed as function arguments. (very few exceptions to this rule: arrays are not converted when used as argument to `sizeof()` and `_Alignof()`.)

- `arry + 1` is an example of such a conversion: `arry` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element, `&(arry[0])`, which has type `int (*)[4]`, a pointer to an array of 4 ints. Adding `1` to it gives a pointer to the next element of the 2D array, `&(arry[1])` with the same type `int (*)[4]`. To print the value of this pointer, you should use `%p` and cast the expression as a pointer to `void`:

  ```
    printf("%p\n", (void *)(arry + 1));
  ```

`%u` expects an `unsigned int`, which may have a different representation and argument passing convention, causing your code to have undefined behavior.

- dereferencing the above pointer, `*(arry + 1)` produces an L-value with type `int [4]` that is the array of 4 ints pointed to by `arry + 1` (more readable as `&(arry[1])`. This array can be used as an argument to `sizeof` and produce `16` if `int` has a size of `4` bytes, but passing it to `printf` causes it to be converted to a pointer to its first element, `&(arry[1][0])`. Again you should use a different syntax to print this address:

  ```
    printf("%p\n", (void *)(*(arry + 1)));
  ```

  The output is the same because the array and its first element have the same address, just like a street and its first house have the same GPS coordinates.

Here is a modified program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arry[3][4] = {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 4, 3, 2, 8 },
        { 7, 8, 9, 0 }
    };
    printf("              arry -> %-16p %s\n", (void *)(arry), "the address of the 2D array");
    printf("      sizeof(arry) -> %-16zu %s\n", sizeof(arry), "the size of the 2D array");
    printf("            arry+0 -> %-16p %s\n", (void *)(arry+0), "the value of a pointer to row 0");
    printf("    sizeof(arry+0) -> %-16zu %s\n", sizeof(arry+0), "the size of a pointer to row 0");
    printf("         *(arry+0) -> %-16p %s\n", (void *)(*(arry+0)), "the address of row 0");
    printf(" sizeof(*(arry+0)) -> %-16zu %s\n", sizeof(*(arry+0)), "the size of row 0");
    printf("           arry[0] -> %-16p %s\n", (void *)(arry[0]), "the address of row 0");
    printf("   sizeof(arry[0]) -> %-16zu %s\n", sizeof(arry[0]), "the size of row 0");
    printf("       &arry[0][0] -> %-16p %s\n", (void *)(&arry[0][0]), "the value of a pointer to row 0, col 0");
    printf("sizeof(arry[0][0]) -> %-16zu %s\n", sizeof(arry[0][0]), "the size of the array element at 0,0");
    printf("        arry[0][0] -> %-16d %s\n", arry[0][0], "the value of the array element at 0,0");
    printf("\n");
    printf("            arry+1 -> %-16p %s\n", (void *)(arry+1), "the value of a pointer to row 1");
    printf("    sizeof(arry+1) -> %-16zu %s\n", sizeof(arry+1), "the size of a pointer to row 1");
    printf("         *(arry+1) -> %-16p %s\n", (void *)(*(arry+1)), "the address of row 1");
    printf(" sizeof(*(arry+1)) -> %-16zu %s\n", sizeof(*(arry+1)), "the size of row 1");
    printf("           arry[1] -> %-16p %s\n", (void *)(arry[1]), "the address of row 1");
    printf("   sizeof(arry[1]) -> %-16zu %s\n", sizeof(arry[1]), "the size of row 1");
    printf("       &arry[1][0] -> %-16p %s\n", (void *)(&arry[1][0]), "the value of a pointer to row 1, col 0");
    printf("sizeof(arry[1][0]) -> %-16zu %s\n", sizeof(arry[1][0]), "the size of the array element at 1,0");
    printf("        arry[1][0] -> %-16d %s\n", arry[1][0], "the value of the array element at 1,0");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
              arry -> 0x7fff512997c0   the address of the 2D array
      sizeof(arry) -> 48               the size of the 2D array
            arry+0 -> 0x7fff512997c0   the value of a pointer to row 0
    sizeof(arry+0) -> 8                the size of a pointer to row 0
         *(arry+0) -> 0x7fff512997c0   the address of row 0
 sizeof(*(arry+0)) -> 16               the size of row 0
           arry[0] -> 0x7fff512997c0   the address of row 0
   sizeof(arry[0]) -> 16               the size of row 0
       &arry[0][0] -> 0x7fff512997c0   the value of a pointer to row 0, col 0
sizeof(arry[0][0]) -> 4                the size of the array element at 0,0
        arry[0][0] -> 1                the value of the array element at 0,0

            arry+1 -> 0x7fff512997d0   the value of a pointer to row 1
    sizeof(arry+1) -> 8                the size of a pointer to row 1
         *(arry+1) -> 0x7fff512997d0   the address of row 1
 sizeof(*(arry+1)) -> 16               the size of row 1
           arry[1] -> 0x7fff512997d0   the address of row 1
   sizeof(arry[1]) -> 16               the size of row 1

       &arry[1][0] -> 0x7fff512997d0   the value of a pointer to row 1, col 0
sizeof(arry[1][0]) -> 4                the size of the array element at 1,0
        arry[1][0] -> 4                the value of the array element at 1,0
```

As you can see, the addresses of `arry`, `arry[0]` and `arry[0][0]` are identical, as would be the values of pointers `&arry`, `&arry[0]` and `&arry[0][0]`

Comment: @chqelir, Thanks it helped. I'm able to understand the expression (arry+i) but somehow I still don't get why *(arry+1) not result into 4 since with arry+1 , we already have pointing to address of element 4 into 1st 1D array ({4,3,2,8} and why *(arry+1) shouldn't give us 4 ??

Comment: @Milan: `arry+1` is a pointer to an object of type **array of 4 ints**, not a pointer to the initial element of this array. Rewriting it as `&arry[1]` underscores the difference with `&arry[1][0]`. `*(arry+1)` is the same as `*&arry[1]`, which is just `arry[1]`, an array of 4 ints (the second row of the matrix).

Comment: Ok, I see this is now decay of the 1st 1-D array (start from ({4,3,2,8} ) points to (& of) to first element of this 1st 1-D array of 4 ints.